# Accessing Refprop with python: SETPATHdll error

Tags: python, dll

I try to access the NIST refprop database via python. for this i downloaded the refprop python module from http://www.boulder.nist.gov/div838/theory/refprop/Frequently_asked_questions.htm

When trying to import the module, I recieve the following error:

```
>>> import REFPROP
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python33\lib\REFPROP.py", line 6525, in <module>
   setpath()
File "C:\Python33\lib\REFPROP.py", line 381, in setpath
   _setpath(path)
File "C:\Python33\lib\REFPROP.py", line 421, in _setpath
   _rp.SETPATHdll(ctypes.byref(_hpth), ctypes.c_long(255))
File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
   func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "C:\Python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
   func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'SETPATHdll' not found 
>>>
```

I found out that this SETPATHdll function is not contained in the refprop.dll file. Still, the module is written for this file. Can anybody help?
Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Use CoolProp with REFPROP wrapper:

installation:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CoolProp/4.2.5

examples:
http://coolprop.sourceforge.net/FluidInformation.html#refprop-fluids-and-mixtures

Comment: I am the primary developer of CoolProp, and it serves as an excellent wrapper of REFPROP.  Please file issues at https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/issues if you run into trouble